# Resultado do método GET traz todas as relações e as subrelações do banco

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-boot, get

Tenho uma aplicação em que eu tenho uma tela de listagem

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou fazendo um método GET na minha API Spring Boot

Classe controller

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/distritos", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Collection<Distritos>> buscarTodosDistritos() {
        Collection<Distritos> distritosBuscados = distritosService.buscarTodos();
            return new ResponseEntity<>(distritosBuscados, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Classe Service

```
public Collection<Distritos> buscarTodos(){
                return distritosRepository.findAll();
            }
```

Classe Repository

```
@Repository
public interface DistritosRepository extends JpaRepository<Distritos, Integer> {

}
```

classe Entidade

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "distritos", schema="glb")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Distritos.findAll", query = "SELECT d FROM Distritos d"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Distritos.findByIdDistrito", query = "SELECT d FROM Distritos d WHERE d.idDistrito = :idDistrito"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Distritos.findByNome", query = "SELECT d FROM Distritos d WHERE d.nome = :nome"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Distritos.findByCodigoDne", query = "SELECT d FROM Distritos d WHERE d.codigoDne = :codigoDne"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Distritos.findByFlagAtivo", query = "SELECT d FROM Distritos d WHERE d.flagAtivo = :flagAtivo")})




@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "idDistrito", scope= Distritos.class)        
public class Distritos implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id_distrito")
    private int idDistrito;


    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 70)
    @Column(name = "nome")
    private String nome;


    @Size(max = 8)
    @Column(name = "codigo_dne")
    private String codigoDne;


    @Column(name = "flag_ativo")
    private Integer flagAtivo;


    @JoinColumn(name="idEntidade")
    @ManyToOne
    private Entidades entidade;


    @JoinColumn(name="idMunicipio")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Municipios municipio;


    @JoinColumn(name="idUf")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Ufs uf;

    public Distritos() {
    }

   gets and sets....
   }
```

e no meu JS do front end eu tenho

```
carregarDados = function() {

        token = localStorage.getItem("userToken");

        $http({
            method : 'GET',
            url : 'http://localhost:8080/user/distritos'
        }).then(function(response) {
            $scope.distritos = response.data;

        }, function(response) {
            console.log(response.data);
            console.log(response.status);
        });
    };
```

o problema é que o retorno do método `GET` traz todas as relações, causando uma demora excessiva, e as suas subrelações, sendo que eu preciso somente do nome do Estado, nome do Municipio e nome da Entidade.

O estranho é que o resultado da segunda listagem do array traz exatamente as informações de que preciso sem as subrelações.

Vejam na imagem.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como eu posso resolver essa questão, trazendo na tela somente as informações que eu quero ?

Answer (score 0):

O erro estava nas minha classes relacionadas, por exemplo, em município, entidade e uf eu tinha um mapeamento `@OneToMany` e dentro dessas classes mais mapeamentos `@OneToMany` que eram desnecessários. Logo, quando eu fazia um `GET` em distritos eu tinha um response com todos os mapeamentos, inclusive bidirecionais que eram desnecessários, ocasionando uma lentidão.